Use the maximum of CPUs allocated to VM
I have a virtual server Use for SQL server and power bi, due to slow processes, I check performance monitor and figure out that my server doesn't use all cores.
here are the screenshots of all things that I check.
Resource Monitor
CPU scheduler
sockets and processors
configured values
Running values
assigned and visibles
and here is my SQL server version
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)   Oct  8 2022 05:58:25   Copyright (C) 2022           Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763:     ) (Hypervisor)
please help how to config for better performance.
Thanks.
ps: due to errors while uploading photos, I had to use spaces , sorry for that , please copy link and open it in new tab.

Here is the general answer for any database server: Do not look at CPU, look at IO. It i generally IO that is the problem, and only once you have debugged that - you start looking at CPU.
Given that this is likely a run the mill hypervisor configuration - I promise you your IO is awful.
